# MATLAB Plot $P = \{x|Ax\leq b\}$

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab, polyhedra

So I am having this trouble with plotting my Polyhedral Set defined as $$P = \{x|Ax\leq b\}$$
The thing is I want to plot it in MATLAB. Let's say my matrix $A$ is $A = [1\ 1 \ ;\ 1\  -1;-5\ 1]$, and my vector $b$ is $b = [0 \ 2 \ 0]$.

How do I plot this polygon in $2D$?

**Thanks!**

Comment: Can you write down the 3 linear inequalities equivalent to your single matrix-vector inequality, taking of course $X=\binom{x}{y}$ in the example you give ?

Comment: Somthing puzzles me: you mention a poly$\color{red}{hedron}$, but the example you take is 2D: it is a poly$\color{red}{gon}$,

Comment: @JeanMarie 
x + y $\leq$ 0;  x - y $\leq$ 2;  y - 5*x $\leq$ 0

Comment: Therefore you just have to plot lines with equations $x+y=0$, $x-y=2$, $y-5x$, determine their intersections and choose the "right side" each time giving you, in this case, a triangle. Is your question meaning that you want to draw the polygon without any preliminary representation ?

Comment: Yes I know the result of these is inequalities is triangle, and I also know that I need to plot the equations, but is there a way to plot just the intersection of these inequalities? So in my figure there is ony filled triangle. Can you understand what I want to achieve? :)

Comment: Things would be simpler if you wor in the first quadrant, i.e., if you add $x\ge 0$ and $y\ge 0$. Besides, do you know linear programming (with its MATLAB function "linprog") ?

Answer (score 0):

I had good experience with plotregion (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9261-plot-2d-3d-region) some years ago. It supports 2d and 3d plots and expects the polyhedral set in the form $Ax \geq b$. Hence, use $\mathtt{plotregion(-A,-b)}$ in your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw the set $\{x | Ax < b\}$ by determining the vertices of the polygon using linear programming (`linprog` function), sorting them (counter)clockwise to eliminate self-intersections, and then using the MatLab `fill` function.
Each edge of the polygon is defined by its endpoints $x_{min, x1}$ and $x_{max, x2}$. They can be obtained by solving the following problems:

minimize $[1, 0]x$ subject to the constraint $Ax \leq b$ and $a_ix = b_i$ (this gives the first point)
minimize $[-1, 0]x$ subject to the constraint $Ax \leq b$ and $a_ix = b_i$ (this gives the second point)

Note that you'll get repetitions as each vertex can be obtained from two different edges, so it's necessary to eliminate duplicates when constructing the vertex list. Also note that a slight modification would be needed when dealing with vertical edges.

This roughly translates to the following matlab script.

```
% get the vertices
m = size(A, 1);
vertices = [];
for i = 1:m
    options = optimoptions('linprog', 'Display', 'none');
    xMinX1 = linprog([1, 0], A, b, A(i, :), b(i), [], [], options);
    xMaxX1 = linprog([-1, 0], A, b, A(i, :), b(i), [], [], options);
    
    if (isempty(vertices) || ~any(all(abs(vertices - xMinX1) < 1e-5, 1)))
        vertices = [vertices, xMinX1];
    end
    if (isempty(vertices) || ~any(all(abs(vertices - xMaxX1) < 1e-5, 1)))
        vertices = [vertices, xMaxX1];
    end
end

% sort the vertices
centroid = mean(vertices);
angles = atan2(vertices(2,:) - centroid(2), vertices(1,:) - centroid(1));
[~, idx] = sort(angles);
sortedVertices = vertices(:, idx);

% draw the set
fill(sortedVertices(1, :), sortedVertices(2, :))
```